# Selenium IDE cannot find Ext JS's column header menu

Tags: javascript, selenium, extjs

I have been using Ext JS for my frontend, and my grid has columns with menus on its headers (just standard impl).

The menu on the header is used to enable, or disable, filters on the store based on the values filled in it.

I have just started using selenium to automate some of my frontend testing, and I figured Selenium cannot find the click action on the column header menu...

I read on the internet that we need to specify unique IDs to components so that Ext JS wont come up with dynamic generated IDs for those. I set an ID to the gridcolumn xtype, but I figured that does not apply to the header menu (or the button that triggers its opening).

Can anyone help me with applying an unique ID to the button that brings up the menu window, or some way to make Selenium find the header menu?

[Ext JS column header menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEVb2.jpg)

Comment: Could you just post the HTML DOM for the header menu from the browser's dev tool?

Comment: @JimGrigoryan I have tried to use that tool last night, without much success. The ids on the div elements are dynamic, and some of the contents of the page can only be accessed with a mouseOver (so I cant access it with XClick's screencapture). Also, there are some elements that cannot be uniquely identified by anything (role, class, id, data-ref).

Can I import an external SS for XClick?

Comment: I just tested it and it works like a charm!! Thank you so very much @JimGrigoryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @JimGrigoryan for the advice! After switching to Kantu's selenium on desktop mode, using XClick, XMove and XMoveRelative I was able to find elements on the page by taking screenshots. Now it does not matter the dynamic IDs Ext Js gives to the elements.

Comment: There are https://ui.vision/rpa/x those Kantu's tools. So XClick, XMove commands are simulated on OS level with this tool, unlike selenium that works just with JavaScript powers.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

**Note**: You need to make little adjusts in the code bellow according to your need.

```java
//find header
WebElement header = findElement(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(.,'Specification Status')]"));

//Make mouse event hover on header for show the arrow
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(header).perform();

//click on arrow
header.findElement(By.cssSelector(".x-column-header-trigger")).click();

//Mouse over event on filter item, this element not linked on header
// findelement no DOM.
WebElement filtros = findElement(By.cssSelector("a[aria-label='Filters'"));
action.moveToElement(filtros).perform();

//find inputs, this element not linked to header
List<WebElement> searchFields = findElements(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Enter Filter Text...']"));

WebElement searchId = searchFields.get(0); //<<< here is according how many inputs is showed in your filters
action.moveToElement(searchId).perform();
searchId.sendKeys("Value to search");

Thread.sleep(1500);
```